# Custom Adapter ListView, setOnCheckedChangeListener not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, android-checkbox

I have read 15+ questions on this topic and none of the solutions have worked for me yet.

I have created a custom Adapter to populate a ListView. Each ListView row contains a single checkbox, and I am trying to capture the checked change event within my custom adapter using  setOnCheckedChangeListener.

When I run the app, I get a null pointer exception on the setOnCheckedChangeListener line.

Here is my custom adapter class:

```
package com.android.toneturtle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapterPlaylist extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Playlist> playlists;
    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListAdapterPlaylist(Context context, ArrayList<Playlist> playlists){
        this.context = context;
        this.playlists = playlists;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // return the number of records in cursor
        return playlists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return playlists.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(view==null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_items, parent, false);
        }

        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        name.setText(playlists.get(position).getName());

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.d("test","i work!");
            }   
        }); 
        return view;
    }
}
```

If anyone could give me a hand with this problem I would be very grateful.

**edit:**
Here is the error logcat

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.toneturtle.ListAdapterPlaylist.getView(ListAdapterPlaylist.java:52)
    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:230)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1171)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2189)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the error logcat

Comment: You would do well to let people know what you've tried so far, so that they don't suggest it to you again.

Comment: check your ids with your xml for row.its not able to find the view

Comment: Tell the line :230 ine HeaderViewListAdapter.java

Comment: yumakikas, I am very new to android and a lot of the solutions I've copied into my code I haven't not fully understood. The copied code has always resulted in a crash so I'm willing to try anything that people say at this point :)

Comment: do you have check box defined in playlist_items.xml

Comment: or show your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou Richa for your help.

I had an incorrect id name in the row.xml file.

...I feel like an idiot :P